# Create CArray of CArray

Tags: arrays, haskell

I want to create a CArray of CArray:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Data.Array.CArray
import Data.Array.Base

testArr :: CArray Int Double
testArr =  listArray (0,5) [0..5]

-- divvyArray :: Int -> CArray Int Double -> CArray Int (CArray Int Double)
divArray w arr = arr'
  where (m1,m2) = bounds arr
        len = m2 - w + 2
        divInd = zip [0..(m2-w+1)] [w..m2]
        f ix = slice (0,w) ix arr 
        arr' = listArray (0,len) [ f k | k <- divInd]
```

The code compiles and has type `divArray :: (Enum p, Shapable p, IArray a1 e, IArray a2 (a1 p e), Ix p, Num p) => p -> a1 p e -> a2 p (a1 p e)'`

But when I run it

> divArray 3 testArray

It gives this error:

```
<interactive>:168:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: IArray a2 (CArray Int Double)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall (a2 :: * -> * -> *).
              IArray a2 (CArray Int Double) =>
              a2 Int (CArray Int Double)
```

Just to give an idea, in `[]`, the result should be:

> divList 3 [0..5]

```
[[0..2],[1..3],[2..4],[3..5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the return type for divArray function as:

```
divArray 3 testArr::CArray Int (CArray Int Double)
```

Otherwise, there is no default CArray instance of Foreign.Storable.Storable classtype. If no such instance, the below error will be arised

> No instance for (Foreign.Storable.Storable (CArray Int Double))

Only the instances of Storable can be element of CArray.